# Set of Ideals of a Polynomial Ring

Tags: ring-theory

How to determine all the ideals of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X^3+1)$?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is exercise 7 in section 9.2 of Dummit and Foote. Is it your homework?

Comment: @Moron: I am trying the find the linear combination of 2 and x^3+1. Because there is a one-to-one correspondence between every ideal of Z[X]/(2,X^3+1) and every ideal of Z[x] containing the ideal (2,x^3+1).

Answer (score 6):

The ring $A={\Bbb Z}[X]/(2,X^3+1)$ is isomorphic to ${\Bbb F}_2[X]/(X^3+1)$ where ${\Bbb F}_2$ is the field with 2 elements. The ideals of the quotient $R/I$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the ideals in $R$ containing $I$. The correspondence is given by the quotient map.

Thus, it's enough to decompose $X^3+1$ in irreducibles over ${\Bbb F}_2$. It is straightforward to check that the decomposition is $X^3+1=(X+1)(X^2+X+1)$. The two factors generate the only two non-trivial ideals in $A$.

Comment: I have seen this result being used several times on multiple questions. How and why is $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2, X^3 + 1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X^3 + 1$?

Comment: @PythonSage: it is a straightforward application f the isomrphism theorem. Send a polynomial modulo $X^3+1$ to itself modulo $2$ and check that the kernel of this map is the ideal generated by $2$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^{3}+1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]/(x^{3}+1)$