# How to think of quotients of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm studying for an algebra midterm and I'm really just having a hard time wrapping my head around quotients of polynomial rings, especially ones where the ideal being quotiented by is something non-principle (i.e an ideal of the form $(x^2 - 2, 3$) in an appropriate polynomial ring).

For example this question [Set of Ideals of a Polynomial Ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19240/set-of-ideals-of-a-polynomial-ring) makes use of the fact that

$$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3 + 1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3 + 1)$$

to arrive at a solution, but this isomorphism doesn't at all seem obvious to me (hopefully because I'm just not thinking about the quotient in the correct way). Another example, also a question from dummit and foote ($\S 9.1, 13$), is ''Prove that the rings $F[x,y]/(y^2 - x)$ and $F[x,y](y^2 - x^2)$ are not isomorphic for any field $F$ ''. Really I don't even see an obvious direction to proceed, but I think, on a more fundamental level, I really just have no intuitive notion as to what those fields even look like.

So I was hoping for some helpful way(s) of thinking about these spaces. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: How comfortable are you with quotients of rings in general?

Comment: Hint: $F[x,y]/(y^2-x^2)$ has (obvious) zero divisors, $F[x,y]/(y^2-x)$ doesn't.

Comment: If you are comfortable with principal ideals but not ideal generated by two elements, first thing you should do is to see what does Ideal generated by two elements mean... For $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2)$ you would just see that you are actually making $2$ to be zero and for $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,x^3+1)$ you want $2$ to be $0$ and then you want $x^3+1$ to be zero in the quotient (in which $2$ is already zero)

Comment: In fact as Mr.Gerry Myerson said one is actually a field and the other is not.. you just have to thank Eisenstein Irreducibility criterion for confirming irreducibility of   $y^2-x$ is in $F[x,y]$

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I wouldn't say I'm comfortable.

Comment: @AndrewRoss : then how about concentrating firstly on Quotient rings in general and then quotient rings of polynomials  with respect to principal ideals and the quotient rings of polynomials with respect to arbitrary ideal....

Comment: Also I've seen things, say $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ where this can be thought of as having $x^2 = -1$, can a similar approach be taken with $F[x,y]/(y^2 - x^2)$? Furthermore, I just don't see why $F[x,y]/(y^2 - x)$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: That $F[x,y]/(y^2-x)$ may not be so easy but do you see this $F[x,y]/(y^2-x^2)$ having zero divisors at least (Which should be obvious?? you just have to see $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Comment: I think so, from what I can tell I'm pretty sure it's because $(y-x)(y+x)$ is zero in the quotient.

Comment: @AndrewRoss : Yes... That is perfect... So, you now believe one ring has zero divisors... you just have to see if there are any in other ring... are you familiar with Eisenstein criterion?

Comment: Yea, but I hate to say it, I don't see how it's applicable.

Comment: What can you say about prime/irreducibility of  $x$  in $F[x,y]$??

Comment: I want to say that Since $F$ is a field, we have that $F[x,y]$ is a UFD, in which case we have that $x$ is prime iff it's irreducible, and since $(x)$ is a prime ideal in $F[x,y]$ (?) we can conclude that $x$ is irreducible. But it looks like in the quotient it is reducible.

Comment: @AndrewRoss : you are unnecessarily complicating your life... :D As $F[x,y]/(x)\cong F[y]$ is a domain but not a field $(x)$ is a prime .... :D As you have $x$ prime in $F[x,y]$ use this prime to say that $y^2-x$ is irreducible in $F[x,y]$.. you might feel comfortable if  you see $y^2-x$ as a polynomial in $y$..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Oh I think I see now, as a polynomial in $y$, $y^2 - x$ is a monic polynomial whose coefficients are all elements of the prime ideal $(x)$, but $x \notin (x)^2$, thus $y^2 - x$ is irreducible by Eisenstein, hence $F[x,y] / (y^2 - x)$ is a field, which furthermore implies that it cant be isomorphic to $F[x,y] / (y^2 - x^2)$?

Comment: @AndrewRoss : That is it and so you are done.....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik : Wow, honestly thank you very much, I'm sure that took alot of patience.

Comment: @AndrewRoss : You are welcome  but then your problem is not totally yet solved right?? what would you do with that misbehaving idiot $\mathbb{Z}[x](2,x^3+1)$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik : Intuitively it looks like since you have 2 in the ideal then basically you're left with only coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, in which case it seems like $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3 + 1) = \{a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 \mid a_i \in \mathbb{F}_2\}$. But really I not very sure.

Comment: Ok.. Tell me if this is acceptable.... In case of ideals,  for some $a,b\in R$ If  $I=(a,b)=(0)$ then $a=0$ and $b=0$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik : Yea that seems acceptable, my understanding is an ideal $I = (a,b)$ is the just the set $\{ra + sb \mid r,s \in R\}$, in which case to have $I = (0)$ would mean that we need $a = b = 0$.

Comment: @AndrewRoss : Do you some how apply that to the quotients??? In quotient ring, you are seeing $(2,x^3+1)$ to be zero ideal so you have..... ???

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik : Oh since $(2, x^3 + 1)$ is zero in the quotient, I have $2 = 0$ and $x^3 + 1 = 0$ in the quotient.

Comment: In some sense yes.... Done!!!

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik : Ahhh I see, very illuminating.

Answer (score 6):

A quotient of rings is a structure where you add a new equation in the previous ring.

For example, $$\mathbb R[T]/(T^2 + 1)$$ is the ring of polynomials, with the new equation $$T^2 + 1 = 0$$so this is $\mathbb C$. So, making a quotient by an ideal generated by 2 elements gives you two new equations. That's all.

1. For the first example, the ring is $\mathbb Z[x]$ with additional equations:
   $$2 = 0 \ \ \& \ \ x^3 = 1$$
   so this is $\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^3 + 1)$ indeed.
2. For the second, consider an isomorphism $f$ from $R_1$ to $R_2$;
   $f(1) = 1$ so $f$ leaves $F$ invariant; it remains to find images of $x,y$ so take the relationship
   $$x^2 = y^2 \ \ \ (R_1)$$
   it implies that $(x+y)(x-y) = 0$, so it should be the case for the images of $x,y$ in $R_2$.

Let $f(x) = P(x,y) = P(y^2,y)$ and $f(y) = Q(x,y) = Q(y^2,y)$.
We have $$(P(y^2,y)+Q(y^2,y))(P(y^2,y)-Q(y^2,y))=0$$ but this is impossible, because it should be true in $\mathbb Z[y]$ which has no $0$ divisors.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is that you need to think about doing algebra with rings. Not with elements of rings, but with the rings *themselves*.

The isomorphism you mention can be easily calculated:

$$ \mathbb{Z}[x] / (2, x^3 + 1) \cong \big(\mathbb{Z}[x] / (2)\big)  / (x^3 + 1) 
\cong \big(\mathbb{Z} /(2) \big)[x]  / (x^3 + 1)  $$

although you might have "seen" it by considering the most natural way to represent elements in the rings: you represent an element by writing down an integer polynomial in $x$, and in both cases, the equivalence relation that two integer polynomials represent the same element is the one generated by $2\equiv0$ and $x^3 + 1\equiv 0$.

Your example $F[x,y] / (y^2 - x)$ is a basic example of another particular sort of simplification: this is isomorphic to the ring $F[y]$ by the evaluation homomorphism $x \to y^2$. That is, the homomorphism $f(x,y) \mapsto f(y^2, y)$.

Comment: See, regarding the step $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (2, x^3 + 1) \cong \big(\mathbb{Z}[x] / (2)\big)  / (x^3 + 1)$, how do you justify 'pulling the 2 out of the ideal'? But what you're saying about $F[x,y] / (y^2 - x)$ seems to make sense.

Comment: I think of it in the terms that modding out by $(a,b)$ is the ring you get by setting $a \equiv 0$ and $b \equiv 0$, so the factorization is obvious. An introductory course would probably mutter something about isomorphism theroems instead: $$R/(I+J) \cong (R/I) / ((I+J)/I)$$ and take care to note that $(I+J)/I$ isn't literally $J$: it's just the ideal of $R/I$ generated by the equivalence classes of the generators of $J$. But IMO, this is more of a "simply stated technical fact" rather than the way to really think about it.

Comment: The universal property I mentioned is that if $f: R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism with the property that $f(a) = 0$ and $f(b) = 0$, then there is a unique homomorphism $g : R/(a,b) \to S$ such that $f = g \circ \pi$. (where $\pi$ is the projection $R \to R/(a,b)$). Similar statements are true for any number of generators. So it really is reasonable to think of $R/(a,b)$ as the ring you get by making as little change to $R$ as possible to make $a=b=0$.

Comment: That's interesting, I think I see what you mean.